# Need help understanding my ElasticSearch Cluster Health

Tags: elasticsearch

When querying my cluster, I noticed these stats for one of my nodes in the cluster. Am new to Elastic and would like the community's health in understanding the meaning of these and if I need to take any corrective measures?
Does the Heap used look on the higher side and if yes, how would I rectify it? Also any comments on the System Memory Used would be helpful - it feels like its on the really high side as well.

**These are the JVM level stats**

```
JVM
Version OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (1.8.0_171)
Process ID  13735
Heap Used % 64%
Heap Used/Max   22 GB / 34.2 GB
GC Collections (Old/Young)  1 / 46,372
Threads (Peak/Max)  163 / 147
```

**This is the OS Level stats**

```
Operating System
System Memory Used %    90%
System Memory Used  59.4 GB / 65.8 GB
Allocated Processors    16
Available Processors    16
OS Name Linux
OS Architecture amd64
```

Comment: no, i don't think you have any problems, at least based on these metrics

Comment: @Mysterion Thanks for the quick reply. Is there a guide that says what is considered a worrying stats ? Especially for the JVM stats above?

Answer (score 0):

As You state that you are new to Elasticsearch I must say you go through cluster as well as cat API you can find documentation at [clusert API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster.html) and [cat API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat.html)

This will help you understand more in depth.